# Windshield repair

Tags: windshield

I cracked my windshield in the very low corner on the passenger's side.  The sharded area is perhaps 10 sq in at the most but then some crack extend out of it and go 6-7 in (2 or 3 of them).

I called my insurance co and they made an appointment for me to try to have it repaired at an auto glass shop for free.  However, they said that if it is too big to be repaired and it needs to be replaced, I will  be responsible for the deductible.

What surprised me was the concept of "windshield repair".  I never knew a windshield can be repaired, i.e. if glass were broken, it should be replaced.  How do you repair broken auto glass?  Just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windshield repairs are usually limited to small chips and small cracks. Several cracks that long will most likely require that the windshield be replaced. The repair is done by injecting a resin into the flaw then polishing the surface. Most shops limit the length to about three inches. There are specialized shops that say the limit is six to eight inches, that is however for a single crack.

Answer (score 4):

First, I have already replaced my Forester's windshield twice, and should go soon for the 3rd time. What surprises me is that your insurance co. charges deductible. Mine was free both times.

From what I heard, when the crack is small enough, then it is possible to carefully drill a circular hole in the glass and then fill it with some kind of bond or resin. It should then have its structural strength again, eliminating the propagation of cracks.

Comment: who is your insurer?  cause i would like to switch.  mine is Geico.

Comment: Its Commerce Insurance. However, it can certainly be a matter of policy and not company.

Comment: Windshields are covered if your policy includes "full glass coverage" which is inexpensive but must be added as it is not part of normal liability coverage.

Comment: Most (if not all) insurers over here (UK) charge for windscreens - and many are now adding a charge for repairs as well...